# Stopping Save/Send document when user exits Spell Check Dialog

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a form that has a basic save button.  In the save button is some code to launch the spell check Dialog.

```
Call uidoc.SpellCheck
```

Is there a way that I can trap return codes from the dialog?  Specifically, I would like the save to stop if the user uses the X in the upper right hand corner to 'Exit' the spell check dialog.

What I am looking for is what type of exits codes the dialog could provide me to stop the save with.  I didn't see anything in the documentation and online help for LotusScript is harder to come by than with other languages.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience the SpellCheck method is too high level to offer any useful return codes you can program against.  It'll simply run the operation and then return.

[Here's a post](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Accessing-the-Notes-mail-send-spell-check-dialog-box) that might help.  Instead of using the uidoc.SpellCheck method, you could optionally enable the "Automatically check mail for misspelling" option which provides the "Cancel Send" button.  Then just a call to save/send the document should trigger the spell check to occur, and allow the user to cancel sending if there are spelling errors.  That is assuming that's the behavior you're after.

Comment: Nice find especially from a site like SearchDomino! The only thing I would add is this sounds like a broadcast/press release app. So it might be sensible to include a human editor in the workflow approval stage since spell cheque (sic) doesn't catch everything!